# What is the view of soul sleep adherents on statements from the Apostolic and ante-Nicene Fathers that seem to support post-mortal consciousness?

Tags: afterlife, christian-mortalism, apostolic-fathers, place-of-the-dead, pre-nicene-fathers

Inspired by the answers I received to my previous question [What did the Apostolic Fathers believe regarding the state of the dead and the afterlife?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/89140/50422), I'm very curious about what proponents of Soul Sleep have to say on this topic.

For example, the [answer](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/89259/50422) I found most convincing and elaborate concludes (emphasis mine):

> **The only topic raised in the OP where the Apostolic Fathers are abundantly clear is post-mortal consciousness--they are decidedly in favor of it**.
>
> Annihilationism does not find clear support in the Apostolic Fathers (but does find much opposition in the writings of their disciples), and proponents of bipartite & tripartite views are unlikely to find compelling evidence one way or the other. Whatever they conclude from reading the Bible will be relatively unchallenged by the writings of the Apostolic Fathers.
>
> ---
>
> **Numerous relevant statements were made by Justin, Irenaeus, Clement of Alexandria, Tertullian, and Origen**–however, I will exclude them from this post per the Meta guidance. **They are ante-Nicene Fathers**, but not Apostolic Fathers. A compilation of many of their relevant statements is found [here](http://www.earlychristiancommentary.com/early-christian-dictionary/dead/).

**Question**: What is the view of soul sleep adherents on statements from the Apostolic and ante-Nicene Fathers that seem to support post-mortal consciousness?

EDIT: see also this [defense](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/74082/38524) of the parable of the rich man and Lazarus as set in reality -- multiple ante-Nicene Fathers are quoted.