# How do Christians who believe that the saints enter a blissful state as soon as they die explain David, Isaiah & Job's pessimistic outlook on death?

Tags: exegesis, afterlife, isaiah, psalms, job

I'm specifically talking about the following passages:

*David*

> “**What profit is there in my death**,
> **if I go down to the pit?**
> **Will the dust praise you?**
> Will it tell of your faithfulness?
> [Psalm 30:9 ESV]

> 4 Turn, O Lord, deliver my life;
> save me for the sake of your steadfast love.
> 5 **For in death there is no remembrance of you**;
> **in Sheol who will give you praise?**
> [Psalm 6:4-5 ESV]

> 17 **The dead do not praise the Lord, nor do any who go down into silence**.
> [Psalm 115:17 ESV]

> 10 Do you work wonders for **the dead**?
> **Do the departed rise up to praise you**? Selah
> 11 Is your steadfast love declared **in the grave**,
> or your faithfulness **in Abaddon**?
> 12 Are your wonders known **in the darkness**,
> or your righteousness **in the land of forgetfulness**?
> [Psalm 88:10-12 ESV]

*Isaiah*

> 9 **Sheol beneath** is stirred up
> to meet you when you come;
> it rouses the shades to greet you,
> all who were leaders of the earth;
> it raises from their thrones
> all who were kings of the nations.
> 10 All of them will answer
> and say to you:
> ‘**You too have become as weak as we**!
> **You have become like us**!’
> 11 **Your pomp is brought down to Sheol**,
> the sound of your harps;
> **maggots are laid as a bed beneath you**,
> **and worms are your covers**.
> [Isaiah 14:9-11 ESV]

> 17 Behold, it was for my welfare
> that I had great bitterness;
> but in love you have delivered my life
> from **the pit of destruction**,
> for you have cast all my sins
> behind your back.
> 18 **For Sheol does not thank you**;
> **death does not praise you**;
> **those who go down to the pit do not hope**
> **for your faithfulness**.
> 19 The living, the living, he thanks you,
> as I do this day;
> the father makes known to the children
> your faithfulness.
> [Isaiah 38:17-19 ESV]

*Job*

> 10 But **a man dies and is laid low**;
> **man breathes his last, and where is he**?
> 11 As waters fail from a lake
> and a river wastes away and dries up,
> 12 **so a man lies down and rises not again**;
> till the heavens are no more he will not awake
> or be roused out of **his sleep**.
> [Job 14:10-12 ESV]

> 13 If **I hope for Sheol as my house**,
> if I make my bed **in darkness**,
> 14 if I say to **the pit**, ‘You are my father,’
> and to **the worm**, ‘My mother,’ or ‘My sister,’
> 15 **where then is my hope**?
> Who will see my hope?
> 16 Will it go down to **the bars of Sheol**?
> Shall we descend together into **the dust**?”
> [Job 17:13-16 ESV]

> 18 “Why did you bring me out from the womb?
> Would that I had died before any eye had seen me
> 19 and were as though I had not been,
> **carried from the womb to the grave**.
> 20 Are not my days few?
> Then cease, and leave me alone, that I may find a little cheer
> 21 before I go—and I shall not return—
> **to the land of darkness and deep shadow**,
> 22 **the land of gloom like thick darkness**,
> **like deep shadow without any order**,
> **where light is as thick darkness**.”
> [Job 10:21-22 ESV]

At face value, it looks like neither David nor Isaiah nor Job believed they would be in paradise, in the presence of God, where they would be able to worship Him and praise Him, as soon as they died. Nor did they seem to have expected to enter into any sort of blissful state. Instead, they refer to death in pessimistic terms, such as silence, darkness, forgetfulness, destruction (other translations say oblivion or nothingness), sleep, worms, maggots, weak, dust, "bars of Sheol", devoid of praise, devoid of hope, etc.

In fact, we find similar pessimistic language in Ecclesiastes chapter 9:

> 5 For the living know that they will die, **but the dead know nothing, and they have no more reward, for the memory of them is forgotten**. 6 **Their love and their hate and their envy have already perished**, and forever they have no more share in all that is done under the sun. [ESV]

> 10 Whatever your hand finds to do, do it with your might, **for there is no work or thought or knowledge or wisdom in Sheol**, to which you are going. [ESV]

**Question**: How do Christians who believe that the saints enter a blissful state as soon as they die explain David, Isaiah & Job's pessimistic outlook on death?

---

[Mirror question](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/73949/38524) on Biblical Hermeneutics Stack Exchange.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133540/discussion-on-question-by-spirit-realm-investigator-how-do-christians-who-believ).

Comment: In a nut-shell, these were all written B.C. David, Isaiah, and Job did go down to Sheol after they died. They were then triumphantly led up to Heaven by Christ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Fear of the unknown**

Death is frightening to many people <sup>[citation needed]</sup> - it represents an unknown, a departure from that which is familiar - these are attributes that make people apprehensive. It is unsurprising that people often look upon death with negative emotion.

For David, death meant leaving behind a remarkably luxurious & powerful mortal existence. As a warrior, he had seen a lot of painful death (e.g. 1 Sam. 18:7), and understandably prayed that this would not be his fate in battle.

For Job, death was the thing that took his family members away (see Job 1:18-19); the reason they were not with him at the moment.

Separation, loss, and the unknown can make death scary even for people who believe in an afterlife.

--

**All 3 believed there was hope**

And yet, this isn't the end of the story. All 3 of the authors referenced in the OP express--in one form or another--a testimony of the resurrection. They're willing to display their human emotion, their fears, their questions--but they don't stop there. Job in particular asks many longing questions that are only answered later in his poetry.

From Job 19:

> 25 For I know that my redeemer liveth, and that he shall stand at the
> latter day upon the earth:
>
> 26 And though after my skin worms destroy this body, yet in my flesh
> shall I see God

This answers questions Job asked earlier in the story. Recovering from trauma is a process, not an event. Job shares much of that process.

From David, in Psalm 16:

> 10 For you will not leave my soul in Sheol, you will not allow your
> holy one to experience corruption.

A New Testament interpretation of this passage is that David will not be left in Sheol because he will be resurrected--and he will be resurrected because the Holy One will not die and decay (He will die and rise again).

From Isaiah 26:

> 19 Thy dead men shall live, together with my dead body shall they
> arise. Awake and sing, ye that dwell in dust: for thy dew is as the
> dew of herbs, and the earth shall cast out the dead.

The songs referenced here sound less like a funeral dirge and more like a celebration.

--

**Long period of bondage**

In this section I will specifically offer a Latter-day Saint perspective.

In his great vision of the spirit world, Joseph F. Smith observed:

> And so it was made known among the dead, both small and great, the
> unrighteous as well as the faithful, that redemption had been wrought
> through the sacrifice of the Son of God upon the cross (Doctrine &
> Covenants 138:35)

Up until this time it was all a promise that had yet to be fulfilled. As Ahmad Corbitt observed:

> All hope for returning resurrected and clean to God's holy presence
> rested entirely upon one Being keeping His promise ([source](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/general-conference/2021/04/32corbitt?lang=eng))

Then, after the Savior's mortal mission had been completed, that hope was being realized. It was a new era for the dead as well.

Continuing from Joseph F. Smith:

> All these and many more [many of the righteous dead have just been
> named]...mingled in the vast assembly and waited for their
> deliverance, For **the dead had looked upon the long absence of their
> spirits from their bodies as a bondage**. (Doctrine & Covenants
> 138:49-50)

I do not claim a solid understanding of how time works in the afterlife, but apparently waiting the equivalent of several centuries for redemption was challenging (if you don't believe waiting--even somewhere comfortable--can be challenging, just ask my children).

Back to Joseph F. Smith once more:

> Thus was it made known that our Redeemer spent his time during his
> sojourn in the world of spirits, instructing and preparing the
> faithful spirits of the prophets who had testified of him in the
> flesh; That they might carry the message of redemption unto all the
> dead... (Doctrine & Covenants 138:36-37, see also 1 Peter 3:18-20,
> 4:6)

A new chapter in the spirit world had opened as well--the impassible gulf could be bridged, and messengers could be sent to proclaim the good news to those who had not received it (or had only a partial understanding). I propose that Isaiah himself rejoiced at the prospect that this would eventually happen:

> The people that walked in darkness have seen a great light: they that
> dwell in the land of the shadow of death, upon them hath the light
> shined. (Isaiah 9:2)

--

**Specific passages**

*Psalm 115:17*

This Psalm contrasts the works of God in heaven with those of men on earth (see verses 3-4).

This theme is emphasized again at the end of the Psalm, as the Psalmist speaks of the blessings God provides to people on earth & the actions people on earth take in worship of God:

> 14 The Lord shall increase you more and more, you and your children.
>
> 15 Ye are blessed of the Lord which made heaven and earth.
>
> 16 The heaven, even the heavens, are the Lord’s: but the earth hath he
> given to the children of men.
>
> 17 The dead praise not the Lord, neither any that go down into
> silence.
>
> 18 But we will bless the Lord from this time forth and for evermore.
> Praise the Lord.

- If the last 2 verses speak of actions taken in the afterlife, they
  contradict one another (i.e. after we're dead we won't praise ^ after
  we're dead we'll still praise for evermore).
- If the last 2 verses speak of actions taken on earth they are quite
  compatible: our people/children (see verse 14) will praise God on
  this earth forever--but from our perspective (on earth) the dead go
  silent--we hear nothing from them. The people who are praising God on
  earth are the living people of Israel (notice there's no mention of
  Sheol here).

Thus the Psalmist either believes:

1. He will never die OR
2. He will praise God for ever--including after he dies OR
3. His people/descendants on earth will praise God forever

#1 conflicts with the message of the Psalm (to say nothing of many of the other Psalms), #2 would support the consciousness of the dead, and #3 (the most likely option) would mean he's just talking about actions on earth.

I suggest #3 fits best with the focus of the Psalm, contrasting the works of God in heaven with those of men on earth. In that case, the Psalmist is quite correct: dead corpses on earth are silent and do not praise God.

*Psalm 6:4-5, Psalm 30:9, Psalm 88:10-12*

These passages highlight the temporal nature of David's concerns. While his spirit is in Sheol, David will not be doing the things he's doing now (in life) to praise God and teach His message. He sees an end to his ability to do what God sent him (David) here to do.

In this Psalm, David is grateful to God for preserving his life on earth and wants to praise & serve God on earth in gratitude. I offered a more extensive discussion of two of these passages in [this post](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/73894/39862) on the Hermeneutics site.

*Job*

All 3 passages from Job raise questions that are later answered in chapter 19. Job is struggling with grief, but after much mental anxiety he ultimately shares his conviction that *there is hope*.

*Isaiah 14:9-11*

All individuals referenced in the passage appear to be wicked--they are not enjoying a blissful afterlife.

*Isaiah 38:17-19*

Death is contemplated with despair--that's a normal human attitude. Isaiah is grateful that his life has been preserved and that he can continue to teach God's message.

*Ecclesiastes 9*

I offered a more extensive discussion of these passages on the Hermeneutics site [here](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/73470/39862). This chapter is focused on events “under the sun”, which refers to the things of this life. In the aforementioned post I also offer a reductio ad absurdum that if Ecclesiastes 9 is used to argue for post-mortal unconsciousness, it could be used to deny the resurrection just as well.

--

**Conclusion**

There are innumerable reasons why a person may feel apprehension about death, or the process of dying. Even Paul, who spoke somewhat favorably about dying, defended himself vigorously when on trial for his life.

Despite their human nature, Job, David, and Isaiah all convey a message of hope through the resurrection, even if not every step of the path between here and there is blissful.

Comment: A note on Psalm 115:17. The last two verses would not contradict each other. The Psalmist is talking about his eternal destiny. Notice that he does not say, "But we will unceasingly bless the Lord from this time forth and for evermore. Praise the Lord." All he says is that he will bless Yahweh forever. He knows that that is his eternal destiny due to the resurrection. For example, I'm sure you will agree that we will live forever with Jesus. We could validly say, "I will live forever with Jesus". Does mean that we will never die? No, only that our eternal destiny is to live forever with Jesus.

Comment: @Rajesh "Those who live and believe in me will never die.  Do you believe this?"

Comment: @MikeBorden - your quote inspired me to ask this [question](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/74282/38524).

Comment: @MikeBorden Let's agree on a few things. (1) It is impossible to be both dead and alive simultaneously. (2) There are 3 types of death; ordinary death, spiritual death(being separated from the **only** true source of life, God), and the Second Death(the lake of fire, eternal destruction/torment). (3) Martha died. So was Jesus talking about ordinary death? If so, he lied to Martha, because she died(which means she is **not** alive; one cannot be dead and alive simultaneously).

Comment: What if Jesus was talking about spiritual death? Would that work? When we have faith in Christ, we are no longer dead in our trespasses and sins; as such, we become a part of the family of God and are connected to the true source of life(this is why we currently have everlasting life[1 John 5:13], even though we aren't actually going to live forever in this current life). If one lives their life believing in Christ and dies an ordinary death, then they would have died while spiritually alive; does that stop them from being connected to God? No! They are still alive in His eyes(Luke 20:38)! :-)

Comment: @Rajesh It is possible to be dead spiritually and alive physically (Ephesians 2) and it makes sense that one may be alive spiritually and dead physically.  I don't take John 11:25-26 to be spoken figuratively.  Jesus did not say that if you believe in him, even if you die, you will be alive *in God's eyes*.

Comment: When I said that it is impossible to be both dead and alive simultaneously I meant for each of the corresponding types of life and death. For example, can one be **both** spiritually alive and spiritually dead simultaneously? I'm sure you agree that's impossible. Likewise, can one be physically dead and physically alive simultaneously? Obviously not. But physical life and spiritual death do not correspond to each other, hence it is fully possible to be both physically alive and spiritually dead(Colossians 2:13). "*you will be alive in God's eyes*" See Luke 20:38; "...for TO HIM all are alive."

Answer (score 1):

We must understand one important point. God does not reside in the place of the dead. God resides in Heaven. This is indisputable.

> Psalm 11:4 The LORD is in His holy temple; the **LORD's throne is in heaven**; His eyes behold, His eyelids test the sons of men.

> 1 Kings 22:19 Micaiah said, “Therefore, hear the word of the Lord. I saw **the Lord sitting on His throne, and all the host of heaven standing by Him** on His right and on His left.

> Isaiah 63:15 **Look down from heaven** and see from Your holy and glorious habitation; Where are Your zeal and Your mighty deeds? The stirrings of Your heart and Your compassion are restrained toward me.

Clearly, God resides in Heaven. And Sheol(שְׁאוֹל), the place of the dead, is notoriously NOT Heaven.

> Genesis 37:35 All his sons and all his daughters rose up to comfort him, but he refused to be comforted and said, “No **I shall go down to Sheol to my son**, mourning.” Thus his father wept for him.

> Numbers 16:30 But if the Lord creates something new, and the ground opens its mouth and swallows them up with all that belongs to them, and **they go down alive into Sheol**, then you shall know that these men have despised the Lord.”

> 1 Samuel 2:6 The Lord **kills** and brings to life; he **brings down to Sheol** and raises up.

> Psalm 18:5 the **cords of Sheol entangled me**; the **snares of death confronted me**.

Those who go to Sheol go *down*, not up, where Heaven is depicted as being(cf. Psalm 14:2, Lamentations 3:41, Matthew 28:2, Luke 24:51, John 20:17). Sheol is not depicted as being a glorious place filled with God's presence. Quite the opposite, in contradistinction with how Heaven is presented(e.g. Psalm 6:4-5, Psalm 16:10, Psalm 18:5, Psalm 88:10-12, Psalm 115:17, Hosea 13:14, Isaiah 38:18-19). Here's my **deductive argument**;

P1: God resides in Heaven(supported by Psalm 11:4, Psalm 14:2, Psalm 18:5, 1 Kings 22:19, Isaiah 63:15, Lamentations 3:41, Matthew 28:2, Luke 24:51, John 20:17).

P2: Sheol is not in Heaven, but a place depicted as being under the earth(as opposed to Heaven being above), full of darkness and silence, devoid of any activity(supported by Genesis 37:35, Numbers 16:30, 1 Samuel 2:6, Psalm 6:4-5, Psalm 16:10, Psalm 18:5, Psalm 30:3, Psalm 49:15, Psalm 88:10-12, Psalm 89:48, Psalm 115:17, Hosea 13:14, Isaiah 38:18-19).

P3: The dead are in Sheol(supported by Genesis 37:35, Numbers 16:30, 1 Samuel 2:6, Job 14:13, Psalm 6:4-5, Psalm 16:10, Psalm 18:5, Psalm 30:3, Psalm 49:15, Psalm 88:10-12, Psalm 89:48, Psalm 115:17, Ecclesiastes 9:10, Hosea 13:14, Isaiah 38:18-19).

C1: God does not reside in Sheol(follows deductively from premises 1 and 2).

C2: The dead are not with God in Heaven, i.e. not in His presence(follows deductively from premise 3 and conclusion 1).

But what about Psalm 139:8? Doesn't it prove that God dwells in Sheol? No. Let's read the context.

> Psalm 139:7-10 Where shall I go from your Spirit?
> Or **where shall I flee from your presence**?
> 8 If I ascend to heaven, **you are there**!
> If I make my bed in Sheol, **you are there**!
> 9 If I take the wings of the morning
> and **dwell in the uttermost parts of the sea**,
> 10 even **there your hand shall lead me**,
> and **your right hand shall hold me.**

Is Psalm 139:8 saying that God literally resides in Sheol? Is it saying that God's literal hand literally holds a person in the uttermost parts of the sea? Or is the Psalmist employing symbolism? If one would fancy taking Psalm 139:8 literally(i.e. to be saying that God actually resides in Sheol), they would be obliged to do the same with the entire context(i.e. both the preceding and succeeding verses). You don't get to pick and choose which parts are literal and which parts are symbolic. My suggestion is that the Psalmist is talking about God's omnipresence, i.e. how God is "everywhere at all times" in the sense that He sees everything and everyone and how nothing and no one is hidden from Him. The words are a metaphor for the **incomprehensible** and **awe-inspiring** omnipresence of God(as well as His omniscience; this is seen in the preceding verses 1-6). Verse 8 is not saying that God literally dwells in Sheol, just as verses 9-10 are not saying that God literally holds us with His right hand in the uttermost parts of the sea, just as verse 5 is not literally saying that God has encircled us from behind and in front, laying His hand on us. It's **symbolic**.

So, in conclusion, righteous ones like David and Isaiah do not currently reside in Heaven. Hope this helps!

Comment: Wait, the question was scoped to *"Christians who believe that the saints go to the presence of God as soon as they die"*. Are you a Christian who believes that the saints go to the presence of God as soon as they die?

Comment: @SpiritRealmInvestigator Oh yes, I'm just realizing that! So sorry, my bad, I failed to pay attention to this question because you had posted one almost identical on BHSE, and I thought this one was just a repeat of that one(the one on BHSE dealt with the exact same passages and exact same subjects of whether or not David/Isaiah thought they were going to Heaven), so I didn't notice this was directed specifically to, as you say, Christians who believe that the saints... etc. etc. But, I wrote an answer, and I'm not going to delete it. So, tell me what you think of it! ;)

Comment: @Rajesh prob better to ask your own Q , now that you have a good answer! And then I upvote the new one!!

Comment: Hey @Rajesh, your insights about heaven and sheol inspired me to ask [this question](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/73970/38524).

Comment: @SpiritRealmInvestigator Yes, I saw, a very very nice question. Good job! I wish I could answer but I can't. I'll give a run down though. "Eternal home" in verse 5 is not a necessary translation. The word for eternal is עוֹלָם, and it can simply mean a long duration of time, not necessarily eternity. For example, Exo 19:9 says that God wants the people to believe Moses עוֹלָם(translated as forever), but obviously, they will be dead someday, so they can't possibly keep believing in Moses for eternity. God just wants the people to believe Moses however long He wants them to, not for eternity.

Comment: There are other examples of עוֹלָם meaning "a long duration of time" as opposed to "for eternity", but you get the point. YLT actually translates what is usually translated as "eternal home" as "age-during home". That's most likely the correct translation. Thus, Ecclesiastes 12:5 is not saying that once we die we go to Sheol for the rest of eternity, but just for a very long time. As for where we go, there's a simple solution. I and you are not our spirits, our spirits are our spirits. We are ourselves. Our spirits go to God, not we go to God. Man(us) goes to our age-during home(Sheol).

Comment: In Genesis 3:19, God does not say, "By the sweat of your brow you will eat your food until your body returns to the ground, since from it your body was taken; for dust your body is and to dust it will return." I've actually **never** seen the body be called dust in all of scripture! It's always that WE ourselves are dust. Psalm 146:4 says that OUR spirit departs and *WE* return to the ground. **Not** we depart and our body returns to the ground. So, a good rule of thumb is to always remember that "dust" is a metaphor for the fragile existence of humanity, not of our bodies. Hope this helps! :)

Comment: @Rajesh - `As for where we go, there's a simple solution. I and you are not our spirits, our spirits are our spirits. We are ourselves. Our spirits go to God, not we go to God. Man(us) goes to our age-during home(Sheol).` - Something in your theory still doesn't make sense to me. If we are a combination of body + spirit, the moment body and spirit part ways at death we cease to exist. Therefore, it wouldn't make sense to say that "we go to Sheol" after death because, under your view, there is no "we", "we" no longer exist. There is no "we" that can go to a place called "Sheol".

Comment: Under your view, the atoms and molecules of my deceased body would go back to earth, and my spirit would go back to God, and therefore the combination of the two would cease to exist, therefore "I" would cease to exist, and it wouldn't make sense to say that "I" go to Sheol, because "I" no longer exist.

Comment: @SpiritRealmInvestigator OH, I see where you got mixed up. No no, see, I'm just speaking from the perspective of Biblical authors, who always depicted Sheol as a place or location. Why? Because how else are you supposed to envision the dead? It's incomprehensible. Try to envision God creating the universe. I bet you're envisioning a being with some spatial dimensions, in a location somewhere. How else can you? Of course, there is no space where God is. Dimensions of space are a part of our universe, but God transcends that, does He not? It is like trying to explain color to a man born blind.

Comment: So you don't believe that Sheol is a real place that truly exists, in a literal sense, in reality (either in the physical realm or the spiritual realm)? You see it as a metaphor, a figure of speech?

Comment: @SpiritRealmInvestigator Yeah, exactly, everything you say is correct. But you can't envision non-existence. Someone from 3000 years ago certainly isn't going to even try. What "Sheol" really is is a metaphor for the state of the dead. "Sheol" is presented as a place with no light or activity, but silence and darkness, because the state of the dead is just that. Sheol is not an actual place you can go to, it is just presented as such for metaphor. Just as God does not actually sit on a throne above the sky looking down at us(Psalm 11:4, Isaiah 63:15), it is just presented as such.

Comment: @SpiritRealmInvestigator Not a figure of speech. Something more powerful than that. Read Job 14:7-17. It's one of my favorite passages in the entire Bible. Here are verses 11-12. "But a man dies and is laid low;
    man breathes his last, and **where is he**?
11 As waters fail from a lake
    and a river wastes away and dries up,
12 **so a man lies down and rises not again;
    till the heavens are no more he will not awake
    or be roused out of his sleep.**" The dead going to Sheol is as real as God sitting on His throne looking down from the sky.

Comment: @SpiritRealmInvestigator It's all about trying to imagine the unimaginable. You can't blame someone for using profound metaphor to do so. Actually, I can't think of any other way to do so. You obviously can't describe the incomprehensible in literal terms(otherwise you would comprehend it), so all that's left is to describe it metaphorically! There's no other way. So yes, Sheol is a metaphor(a deep and profound one) for the incomprehensible state of the dead. Does that clear up whatever you're thinking? Do you fully understand what "*Man(us) goes to our age-during home(Sheol)*" means?

Comment: @Rajesh - I wouldn't put much stock on Job 14 as the foundation for my afterlife theology given how controversial this chapter is and given that one could arguably say that Job didn't show significant evidence of belief in a future resurrection. See https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/23117/what-is-job-saying-he-believes-about-death-and-what-follows-in-job-14

Comment: @Rajesh: `Do you fully understand what "Man(us) goes to our age-during home(Sheol)" means? ` - it depends on what is meant by Sheol. What are your thoughts on the Book of Enoch? See https://www.sacred-texts.com/bib/boe/boe025.htm

Comment: "*that one could arguably say that Job didn't show significant evidence of belief in a future resurrection*" This can't be a serious statement. Job had **significant belief in a future resurrection**! When Job says "a man lies down and rises not again", what does he then say right after? You must take that statement in context. "till the heavens are no more he will not awake or be roused out of his sleep." Job is saying that a man rises not again UNTIL the heavens are no more(Psalm 102:25-26, Isaiah 34:4, Isaiah 51:6, Mark 13:31, Luke 21:33, Matthew 24:35, 2 Peter 3:10-12, Revelation 21:1).

Comment: What are your thoughts on the beliefs of the Apostolic Fathers (first 2 centuries)? See https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/89140/50422

Comment: @Rajesh - I think you should post an answer to the Apostolic Fathers question then :-). By the way, I recently asked this other question on Job 14:12: [Can Job 14:12 be interpreted as an eschatological statement about a future resurrection of the dead?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/73981/38524)

Comment: @Rajesh - sounds like you are a cessationist, no supernatural revelations from God outside the Bible :-). See [How do continuationists respond to the 'closed canon' argument against the continuation of special revelations and sign gifts?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/85908/50422)

Comment: @Rajesh - inspiration is clearly supernatural (comes from God) and is clearly revelatory (previously unknown information is revealed, there is transmission of information), so the semantics match up well.

Comment: @Rajesh - In the act of inspiration, do you believe that: 1) there is any element of divine intervention whatsoever? Is God intervening in any way, shape or form in the world? Isn't that supernatural? 2) is new information gained?

Comment: 2 Timothy 3:16 ***All Scripture is breathed out by God** and profitable for teaching, for reproof, for correction, and for training in righteousness* - that's supernatural.

Comment: 2 Peter 1:20 *20 knowing this first of all, that **no prophecy of Scripture comes from someone's own interpretation**. 21 **For no prophecy was ever produced by the will of man, but men spoke from God as they were carried along by the Holy Spirit**.* - that's supernatural.

Comment: @Rajesh - I disagree with your disagreement regarding **No. 2**. God certainly intervened supernaturally in the process of having Matthew become an eyewitness. Supernatural things happened all the time during the onset of Christianity and God providentially made it so that Matthew witnessed them. So you have all the ingredients: 1) supernatural/divine intervention and 2) Matthew gaining new information that he previously didn't know. All providentially orchestrated by God.

Comment: `it's not "God providentially making someone witness something", it's God revealing something to someone through a vision or dream or an OBE as you are constantly talking about` - 1) those are **examples** of how God can intervene supernaturally in order to communicate a message to you, but those examples are by no means **exhaustive**; 2) even in those examples, you are still witnessing something. Back to your example of Matthew: Matthew was very much in touch with the supernatural. He witnessed the supernatural ministry of Jesus, who was sent by God the Father.

Comment: The whole testimony of Matthew is impregnated with the supernatural. The whole ministry of Jesus, which he witnessed, was supernatural. The resurrection was supernatural. Matthew being prompted to be a witness was also supernatural. And he gained eyewitness knowledge through that. And he wrote it down. That's supernatural revelation of information from God to Matthew, and through Matthew to the rest of the world through his gospel.

Comment: `For example, God did not intervene to reveal hidden knowledge to Matthew. All Matthew did was look with his own eyes at what was happening.` - And that's exactly the way God revealed hidden knowledge to Matthew!  Read Matthew 13:17 *For truly I tell you, **many prophets and righteous people longed to see what you see but did not see it, and to hear what you hear but did not hear it**.*

Comment: `God did not directly intervene using supernatural powers to reveal anything to Matthew. Matthew simply saw with his regular eyes what was happening, as did many, many other people` - And what was happening was supernatural! The miracles of Jesus were supernatural! The resurrection of Jesus was supernatural!

Comment: @Rajesh - if at least one element in the process of revelation is supernatural, the whole thing can be classified as supernatural. In a vision, you can still use your brain and think about it, and then write it down through natural means. Does that make it natural? Matthew witnessed tons of supernatural things, so he received supernatural revelations.

Comment: You had said that one can make a case for Job **not** believing that a resurrection is possible, and thus his words are unreliable as a foundation for afterlife theology(I wasn't making them one, but either way). Can you give me some details? What suggests that Job might not believe in a resurrection?

Answer (score 0):

There are many things presented in the OT, many topics covered or touched upon in the context of historical narrative, poetry, wisdom literature, etc. which, read apart from the new light shed in the pages of the NT, are less than full treatments.  That is not to say that the OT is inaccurate or even incomplete but it is, standing by itself, unfulfilled and oft times unexplained.

The prophets and holy men of old who penned the words of the OT often had [little or no clarity](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1%20Peter%201%3A10-12&version=KJV) regarding the very things they wrote and read:

> For I tell you that many prophets and kings desired to see what you see, and did not see it, and to hear what you hear, and did not hear it. - Luke 10:24

And, while that which is contained in the pages of the OT is sufficient ground for the faith by which salvation comes (Hebrews chapter 11 lists many righteous), it is not ground for perfection of faith:

> And all these, though commended through their faith, did not receive what was promised, since God had provided something better for us, that apart from us they should not be made perfect. - Hebrews 11:39-40

This perfection extends toward a perfection of understanding now that the promised Christ has come and sent forth the Spirit of Truth into the hearts of the redeemed to guide them into all truth:

> “I still have many things to say to you, but you cannot bear them now. When the Spirit of truth comes, he will guide you into all the truth, for he will not speak on his own authority, but whatever he hears he will speak, and he will declare to you the things that are to come. He will glorify me, for he will take what is mine and declare it to you. All that the Father has is mine; therefore I said that he will take what is mine and declare it to you. - John 16:12-15

One striking example of this is the Apostle Paul allegorizing the historical record of Sarah, Hagar, and their children by Abraham.  Paul plainly states that these are two covenants allegorically:

> For it is written that Abraham had two sons, one by a slave woman and one by a free woman. But the son of the slave was born according to the flesh, while the son of the free woman was born through promise. Now this may be interpreted allegorically: these women are two covenants. One is from Mount Sinai, bearing children for slavery; she is Hagar. Now Hagar is Mount Sinai in Arabia; she corresponds to the present Jerusalem, for she is in slavery with her children. But the Jerusalem above is free, and she is our mother. - Galatians 4:22-26

And then Paul quotes Isaiah 54:1

> Sing, O barren one, who did not bear; break forth into singing and cry aloud, you who have not been in labor! For the children of the desolate one will be more than the children of her who is married,” says the LORD. - Isaiah 54:1

indicating that the children of promise (those in Christ who are Abraham's offspring) are the subject in view.  Just reading Isaiah 54 alone one understands Israel/Jerusalem as the subject matter but Paul points out that the Jerusalem below is in bondage with her children (like Hagar) while the children of promise are free.

Without the NT interpretation it is very difficult, perhaps impossible, to understand that Isaiah 54 refers to spiritual Israel rather than national Israel.

There are many, many examples of such things and the condition of the dead is one of those topics.  Just as it would be inappropriate to lessen the import and insight of Paul's teaching by forcing it through the interpretive lens of Isaiah so it is with OT statements of the condition of the dead.  When Paul declares:

> For to me to live is Christ, and to die is gain. If I am to live in the flesh, that means fruitful labor for me. Yet which I shall choose I cannot tell.  I am hard pressed between the two. My desire is to depart and be with Christ, for that is far better. But to remain in the flesh is more necessary on your account. - Philippians 1:21-24

it is not appropriate to force his departure and presence with Christ to contain an unspoken waiting period of unconscious deadness imposed by a strictly OT understanding.  Paul is speaking of immanence:  He will either remain in the flesh or be with Christ.

Elsewhere, when Jesus corrects the Sadducees regarding the resurrection of the dead:

> And as for the resurrection of the dead, have you not read what was said to you by God: ‘I am the God of Abraham, and the God of Isaac, and the God of Jacob’? He is not God of the dead, but of the living.” - Matthew 22:31-32

It is not appropriate to impose upon Jesus' teaching the same limited OT understanding which the Sadducees themselves held and which Jesus corrected.

It is much more appropriate to look back into the old testament through the new testament lens of increased revelation and understand that such statements as:

> The Lord kills and brings to life; he brings down to Sheol and raises up. - 1 Samuel 2:6

are spoken completely ignorant of the new revelation contained within the fulfillment of the promise of Christ:

> “I am the resurrection and the life. Whoever believes in me, though he die, yet shall he live, and everyone who lives and believes in me shall never die. Do you believe this?” - John 11:25-26

Without the NT enlightenment the OT reports exactly what the natural man sees as regards the dead:  The body is bereft of whatever quickening force animates it (no movement, no thought, no understanding) and goes into the ground with all the other dead (Sheol).  While there certainly can be an OT expectation of a resurrection from the dead (wherever and however they are) it is the NT which declares the immediacy and permanence of that resurrection:

> Truly, truly, I say to you, whoever hears my word and believes him who sent me has eternal life. He does not come into judgment, but has passed from death to life. “Truly, truly, I say to you, an hour is coming, and is now here, when the dead will hear the voice of the Son of God, and those who hear will live. - John 5:24-25

God is the God of the living and not of the dead.  He **is** the God of Abraham not *will someday be again* the God of Abraham.  It is the NT which should interpret the OT not the other way around.  Astonishingly, Abraham is truly dead (OT understanding) and yet truly alive (NT understanding).

> And when the crowd heard it, they were astonished at his teaching. - Matthew 22:33

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133799/discussion-on-answer-by-mike-borden-how-do-christians-who-believe-that-the-saint).

Comment: Please use chat for this discussion.

Comment: None of this answer has any direct references that support the idea we go to heaven after we die. This new light nonsense has no bearing on that. As another point...if we go to heaven when we die, why the need for the second coming? The second coming itself does not agree with your argument...we do not need the second coming so that sinful bodies may be raised, transformed, and to join up with spirits that have already been ith God in heaven...it doesn't even make logical sense.

Comment: @Adam OP is not asking for a defense of the idea that we go to heaven after we die.  OP is asking how those who believe such a thing handle OT texts that appear antagonistic to that idea.

Comment: How does this answer or even address the question?

Comment: @Dottard The point is that Isaiah, David, and Job, etc.,  read on their own without the light of the NT are not full treatments.  They are things seen through a glass darkly and their statements about the period interim between death and resurrection need to be understood in that light.

Comment: @MikeBorden - true but they are still inspired writings and so are not wrong but profitable for instruction just as much as the rest of scripture.  Job understood the resurrection clearly, Job 19:20-26.

Comment: @Dottard I guess that, rather than expressing pessimism regarding death and the period leading up to resurrection, it is more like a degree of  earth-centric ignorance that is expressed.  Hold To The Rod has a fine treatment of this in the second half of his answer above.

Answer (score 0):

One response is that these were all written Before Christ.

On this understanding, David, Isaiah, and Job did go down to Sheol after they died. They were then triumphantly led up to Heaven by Christ.

The exact timing of this varies. The Roman Catholic church holds that by His death and resurrection, Jesus opened Heaven (CCC 1026, [637](https://www.usccb.org/sites/default/files/flipbooks/catechism/166/)). Jesus by descending to Sheol freed those who had gone before Him (CCC [633](https://www.usccb.org/sites/default/files/flipbooks/catechism/166/)).

Note whether all who go to Heaven after Jesus' resurrection, go immediately to Heaven is [debated](https://catholic-link.org/souls-heaven-hell-die/) within Catholicism.

Others hold they were led to Heaven ~A.D. 70, when Jesus returned to judge Jerusalem and definitively ended the Old Covenantal age.

In either case, the basic response is that David et al.'s views were correct for when they were writing, but are no longer correct.